# An ActionMethodSelectorAttribute that applied to all actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want my selector applied to all actions but I don't want to copy and paste it everywhere.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public abstract class ActionMethodSelectorAttribute : Attribute

public class VersionAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        //my logic here
    }
}
```

`GlobalFilterCollection.Add` is not working in this case because it's not a `FilterAttribute`. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to come up with a nicer way to do this?

Comment: @nfplee: At last I use another solution to bypass this issue...

Comment: Would your solution help solve my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613369/asp-net-mvc-global-selector-attribute? If so I'd appreciate your feedback even if it's only to point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: @nfplee: Sorry I didn't resolve this issue, I just apply another solution so that I won't be headache for this problem any more...

Comment: Thanks this looks like what I might have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took this as some kind of challenge - trying to inject custom `ActionMethodSelector` into list of existing ones. *Though I haven't found any bullet-proof way to do this,  I'll share what I've come up with yet*

1.Create custom `ActionInvoker` and try to inject selector. I used the default `ReflectedActionDescriptor`, as it already contains `MethodInfo` to test `MyActionMethodSelector` against.

```
public class MyActionInvoker : ControllerActionInvoker
{
    protected override ActionDescriptor FindAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, string actionName)
    {
        var action = base.FindAction(controllerContext, controllerDescriptor, actionName);

        if (action != null)
        {
            var reflectedActionDecsriptor = action as ReflectedActionDescriptor;
            if (reflectedActionDecsriptor != null)
            {
                if (new MyActionMethodSelectorAttribute().IsValidForRequest(controllerContext, reflectedActionDecsriptor.MethodInfo))
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        return action;
    }
}
```

2.Inject `MyActionInvoker` into controllers. To do that, derive all of controllers from `MyBaseController`, implemented as

```
public class MyBaseController : Controller
{
    protected override IActionInvoker CreateActionInvoker()
    {
        return new MyActionInvoker();
    }
}
```

That's it for now :)

Comment: I also considered this solution, it *should* work I think. Just wondering if there is a easier way...

Comment: `base.FindAction` may throw an `AmbiguousMatchException` exception here, because I have a few actions with the same name in a controller, that's why I need a selector. Their name can't be changed because old clients are still using them. I'm currently versioning them.

Comment: @DannyChen oh, if that's the situation, you're right, solution will not work for you

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly change it to the following:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class VersionAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    private bool IsValidForRequest(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //my logic here
        return true; //for testing
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!IsValidForRequest(filterContext))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpNotFoundResult();  //Or whatever other logic you require?
        }
    }

    public void  OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //left blank intentionally
    }
}
```

And then register this as a global filter:

```
filters.Add(new VersionAttribute());
```